# Is there another way to choose blue and red color one by one?

Tags: python, python-turtle

It's coded to go from `100` to `0` radius circles one by one like red, blue, red, blue. I did it with if else but I am sure I can do that in a more advanced way like random,lists or whatever. Can you help with that?

```
import turtle
screen = turtle.Screen()
turtle = turtle.Turtle('turtle')
turtle.pensize(3)
turtle.pencolor('red')
def circle(x, y, r):
    if r <= 0:
        return
    turtle.penup()
    turtle.goto(0, -r)
    turtle.pendown()
    turtle.circle(r)
    if (turtle.pencolor() == 'red'):
        turtle.pencolor('blue')
    else:
        turtle.pencolor('red')
    circle(0, 0, r-10)

circle(0, 0, 100)
screen.exitonclick()
```

Comment: Debugging code is at least twice as hard as writing it in the first place. So if you write your code as cleverly as you can,  you are by definition not clever enough to debug it later. Translation: you don't need to make your code more clever/advanced just for the sake of it. Your code is functional and readable as it is

Answer (score 5):

You can use [`itertools.cycle`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.cycle) to, well, cycle through the colors:

```
from itertools import cycle

colors = cycle(["red", "blue"])

# ...
def circle(...):
    turtle.pencolor(next(colors))  # will assign alternating values
    # ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of 4 lines for if-else, you can use a ternary operator to set color in one line:

```
color = "red" if turtle.pencolor() == "blue" else "blue"
turtle.pencolor(color)
```

It saves a few lines but it doesn't really optimize anything compared to yours.